# String s="red,green,green,red,red,green,green,red"; if the combination will occur more than once "red,green" or "Green,red".(Count)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a comma-separated string which have words:

```
String s = "red,green,green,red,red,green,green,red";
```

if the combination occurs more than once "red,green" or "Green,red", I want to capture the number of occurrences in the string (count). Could anyone help me with this for better time and space complexity solution?

Comment: What would be the expected output in this case?

Comment: Also, how many different terms may be in the input? ie is it only composed of "red" and "green"?

Comment: Case-sensitive?

Comment: Can they overlap? Is “red,green,red” one occurrence or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex.

**Upto Java 8**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "red,green,green,red,red,green,green,red";
    Pattern rGPattern = Pattern.compile("(red,green)");
    Pattern gRPattern = Pattern.compile("(green,red)");
    Matcher rGMatcher = rGPattern.matcher(s);
    Matcher gRMatcher = gRPattern.matcher(s);

    int rGCount = 0, gRCount = 0;
    while (rGMatcher.find()) {
        rGCount++;
    }
    while (gRMatcher.find()) {
        gRCount++;
    }

    System.out.println("red,green occurrence: " + rGCount);
    System.out.println("green,red occurrence: " + gRCount);
}
```

**For Java 9+**

replace the following segment:

```
int rgCount = 0, gRCount = 0;
while (rGMatcher.find()) {
    rgCount++;
}
while (gRMatcher.find()) {
    gRCount++;
}
```

with

```
long rGCount = rGMatcher.results().count();
long gRCount = gRMatcher.results().count();
```

You'll get:

```
red,green occurrence: 2
green,red occurrence: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in the example you've provided, you have 4 pairs of "red,green" or "green,red". If that's the case, here's how you could do it:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "red,green,green,red,red,green,green,red";
        String[] splitted = s.split(",");
        
        int numberOfOccurences = 0;
        boolean lastRed = false;
        boolean lastGreen = false;
        
        for(String entry : splitted){
            if(entry.equals("green")){
                if (lastRed == true){
                    numberOfOccurences++;
                }
                lastGreen = true;
                lastRed = false;
            }
            else if (entry.equals("red")){
                if (lastGreen == true){
                    numberOfOccurences++;
                }
                lastRed = true;
                lastGreen = false;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("The number of 'red,green' or 'green,red' is " + numberOfOccurences);
    }
}
```

In this case, the time complexity is O(n) (n being the number of "red" or "green" words).

The space complexity is O(1): even if `s` contain many words, the memory size of the program would not increase besides the size in memory of the variable `s`.